# Moving an image across a GUI in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, timer

So I have to move my (multiple) images across a GUI, but for whatever reason my paint method is only being called twice, even though my x variable and my timer, which I am using to try and move the image, are incrementing correctly.    Any help would be appriciated! Thanks

```
  import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;


public class Races extends JFrame 
{
public int threadCount = 5;
public int x = 0;
public ImageIcon picture = new ImageIcon("races.jpeg");
public int height = picture.getIconHeight();
public int width = picture.getIconHeight();


public Races(int _threadCount)
{
   threadCount = _threadCount;
   int counter = 0;
   while(counter<threadCount)
   {
      (new Thread(new RacesInner(threadCount))).start();
      counter++;
   }
   initialize();
}



  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     if(args.length == 0)
     {
         JFrame f = new Races(5);
       }
        else
     {
        JFrame f = new Races(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    }   
   }


    public void initialize()
   {
     this.setVisible(true);
        this.setTitle("Off to the Races - By ");
      RacesInner inner = new RacesInner(threadCount);
       this.add(inner);
      this.setSize((width*20),(height*3)*threadCount);
       this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       this.repaint();
   }   


    protected class RacesInner extends JPanel implements Runnable
    {
        public int j = (int)(Math.random() * 50) + 20;

         public void timer()
          {
          Timer timer1 = new Timer(j, new ActionListener()
          {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
              {
                   x += 2;
                    repaint();
             }
          });
          timer1.start();
          }


         public void run()
        {
            timer();
         }

       @Override
       public void paint(Graphics g) 
       {
         super.paintComponent(g);
        //drawing the correct amount of icons based on input(or lack of input, default 5)

          //Get the current size of this component
          Dimension d = this.getSize();
         //draw in black
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        //calculating where finish line should be and drawing the line 
        int finishLine;
        finishLine = (width*20)-(width*2);
         g.drawLine(finishLine,0,finishLine,2000);
         for(int i =0; i<threadCount; i++)
        {
         picture.paintIcon(this,g,1+x,(50*i)); 
        }
      }

      public RacesInner(int _threadCount)
      {
         threadCount = _threadCount;
         System.out.println(threadCount);

          //JPanel
         this.setVisible(true);
          this.setLayout(new GridLayout(threadCount,1)); 
      }

   }//closes RacesInner class


 }//closes races class
```

Comment: Some funky code up there including starting a Swing Timer in a background thread (?), calling super.paintComponent inside of a paint method override... I think it best if you go through the Swing Timer tutorial and Swing painting tutorials.

Comment: That was due to changing things up to try things out, I just cannot figure out THIS problem

Comment: THIS problem is still related to the issues I've raised. I recommend that you re-write your code and get rid of the funkiness. Override a JPanel's paintComponent method and call the same super method in the override. Use a Swing Timer but don't call it from a background thread. Then come back with the new code if still having problems.

Comment: The paintcomponent problem is already fixed, if you could give me more information on what you mean by background threads I would be very appreciative

Comment: You've got your Timer starting in a Runnable's run method that is started by calling `start()` on a Thread. You are creating background threads and you should never make Swing calls, including starting a Swing Timer, from within a background thread.

Comment: In fact, I suggest that you get rid of all Thread objects, all Runnables in your code above. Just use a Swing Timer, and that's it.

Comment: I used the Threads as eventually, I Would like multiple moving objects all moving at different increments (using math.random() ), I just haven't gotton there yet.

Comment: I have got all my pictures to move, though I thought they would be each be moving using a thread, but they are all moving at the same incriment on the same thread, thoughts?

Comment: Thoughts: get rid of your threads. Use a Swing Timer. Give each object its own velocity that decides how much to move with each time slice. Regardless, if you feel you must use threads, again, don't make Swing calls from a background thread, period.